# How to obtain haxe compiler version at runtime

Tags: haxe

I would like to display the haxe compiler version on screen. Something like:

`var ver = haxe.version; // does not exist`

Command line "haxe -version" displays the version (3.2.1 in my case).

Checking the [haxe source on github](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/src/main.ml), it appears the compiler version is set in the compiler program main, and does not seem to be accessible from a Haxe program.

Any idea how to do this? A macro maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the haxe version or the value of any define with:

```
haxe.macro.Compiler.getDefine("haxe_ver");
```

http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/#ABb7a

**EDIT:**

- [Documentation of getDefine](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/Compiler.html#getDefine)
- [List of compiler flags/definitions](http://haxe.org/manual/compiler-usage-flags.html)

You'll find `haxe-ver` in there.

Comment: Thanks Justo, works fine. I added links to compiler flags for future reference (if you accept the edit).